# iptables is not blocking traffic

Tags: iptables

I have set an INPUT DROP policy and allowed only my IP address to access the server.
Still when using iftop / nload it shows tons of packets from different IPs addresses to port xxxx.
Users report they are unable to access the service, still packets coming from everywhere are shown in iftop, don't know if there is a SO vulnerability there, I am using CentOS 7

I added the rules before disabling my VPS provider firewall (it is limited to 20 rules) to make sure there were no connections except mine when iptables rules in the SO were added.

iptables -L shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  x.x.x.0/24 (my IP)      anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Am I missing something?

I forgot to mention I am trying to disable all traffic because my service is under attack (nload shows 600 kbps when attacked, iptables on or off make no difference)

EDIT

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 10 17:44:19 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [23224058:743302427]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [640828:98031836]
[653685:116395213] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[6:384] -A INPUT -s x.x.x.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 10 17:44:19 2021
```

Comment: .?! *ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere* first match wins!

Comment: state RELATED,ESTABLISHED ?

Comment: Please replace inaccurate `iptables -L` with much more comprehensive `iptables-save -c`.

Comment: I have added the information requested

Comment: So unless you changed your rules recently (which allows pre-existing flows to continue to exist because of the shortcircuit ESTABLISHED rule) , your ruleset allows only traffic from local LAN, (and not even traffic from 127.0.0.1). I can't make an answer telling "all is fine" since you think it's not fine. It depends on the captured traffic you'd get with tcpdump. Bear in mind this captured traffic happens before it's dropped. Also any outgoing traffic is allowed replies. So for a paranoid example: if you already have a trojan, it gets no problem to communicate with outside, both ways.

Comment: @Simon Ah, It was not obvious in the mobile app.

Comment: Is there even a way to capture traffic after the firewall rules are applied? I thought the traffic captured by nload/iftop was the allowed after the firewall